# R - rbind two data frames and delete extra IDs

Tags: r

I've two DFs

```
> df1
id type
1 a
2 b
3 f
4 t
5 y

> df2
id type
1 D
2 V
3 f
4 t
5 y
6 z
7 p
8 x
```

I want to get the following output

```
id type
1 a
2 b
3 f
4 t
5 y
1 D
2 V
3 f
4 t
5 y
```

Basically, I want to to join (rbind) the DFs and delete the IDs which are not existing in both DFs.

Comment: You shouldn't change your data once answers have been given because you may invalidate those answers.

Comment: i know but i only change the column names in the DFs. I just thought there were some misunderstanding

Comment: No, I did not change your data and that fact is fully visible in the edit history, which I guess you assumed was not publicly visible.

Comment: `rbind(df1,df2[df2$id %in% df1$id,])`

Comment: @Frank i am sorry. it was not you that was Tim Biegeleisen who changed the column name. IDK why he did that

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChirayuChamoli that solved my problem

Comment: `library(dplyr); bind_rows(df1, semi_join(df2, df1, by = 'id'))`

Answer (score 1):

One strategy here is to take the inner product of the IDs between the two data frames, and then `rbind()` the remaining `b` and `a` columns together:

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, by="id")
rbind(df[,c("id", "b")], setNames(df, c("id", "z", "b"))[, c("id", "b")])
```

**Output:**

```
   id b
1   1 a
2   2 b
3   3 f
4   4 t
5   5 y
6   1 D
7   2 V
8   3 f
9   4 t
10  5 y
```

**Data used:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1:5), b=c('a', 'b', 'f', 't', 'y'))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1:8), a=c('D', 'V', 'f', 't', 'y', 'z', 'p', 'x'))
```

Comment: @Frank You changed the original data of the problem.  I'm changing it back now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen why did you change the col name in the question?

Comment: @TomHart I thought you originally had different column names before Frank's edit.  In any case, that doesn't invalidate my answer.

Comment: yeah, but your answer is not working for me :( i got this error - Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , c("id", "b")) : undefined columns selected

Comment: My answer certainly works with the data I provided.  What isn't working?  Again...don't mess with the data.

Comment: i did not miss with it. Frank's changed the question and i just changed back to the original problem i have. the two DFs have the same column names. can you please edit your answer to solve my problem and i really appreciate it

Comment: may i ask you why did you change the column name in the question from b to a ?

Comment: Where exactly in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43648748/revisions) did you spot Frank changing that data, Tim? Unless you feel that the [tag:rstudio] was very critical here.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Maybe I'm mistaken.  I could have sworn that initially the two data frames had columns with different names.  And in the general case a solution which allows for this is useful IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your input as `df1` and `df2`, you can try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = "id") %>% 
  gather(key = eh, value = meh, -id) %>%
  select(id, meh)
```

which gives:

```
   id meh
1   1   a
2   2   b
3   3   f
4   4   t
5   5   y
6   1   D
7   2   V
8   3   f
9   4   t
10  5   y
```

p.s. with the new column names, it becomes important to specify the `by` argument for the `join`